# PHP Variable returned on echo

Tags: php

I am using this statement but for some reason when my variable is 0 instead of getting the output "See Description"  - i am getting the output "0 See Description".

Why does this happen?

```
$sinput = get_field('fl_area');
$soutput = sqFeetToMeters($sinput); 
if(trim($sinput) == "0"){echo ' See Description ' ;} else {echo $soutput . ' sq. m (' . number_format($sinput ) . ' sq. f)' ;}
```

Comment: Check that you have not forgotten another `echo` in your code (in previous lines or in functions `get_field` or `sqFeetToMeters`).

Comment: i dont think so - but i will double check..

Comment: show code for `get_field` and `sqFeetToMeters` please, check if it has `print` `echo` or `print_r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test that your other functions are not echo'ing anything, please an echo before the

```
if(trim...
```

statement. If your response is now

```
0 [your echo output] See Description
```

you will know what the issue is.

Comment: sqFeettoMeters was the problem... thanks solved now